# Even sized buttons in linear layout

Tags: android

I have a linear layout that's part of a tablerow

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp" >

            <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="50dp" android:id="@+id/button11" android:background="@drawable/page1p" android:layout_width="0dp"></Button>
            <Button  android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button21" android:layout_height="50dp" android:background="@drawable/page2x" android:layout_width="0dp"></Button>
            <Button  android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button31"  android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:background="@drawable/page3x"></Button>
            <Button  android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button41" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:background="@drawable/page4x"></Button>
            <Button  android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button51"  android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:background="@drawable/page5x"></Button>
            <Button android:layout_weight="1"  android:id="@+id/button61"  android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:background="@drawable/page6x"></Button>
            <Button  android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="50dp" android:id="@+id/Button71"  android:layout_width="0dp" android:background="@drawable/page7x"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
```

what i am trying to do is have it so that no matter how many buttons are added to this layout, they will always resize to fit the width evenly. i have tried changing to to imagebuttons but it does not help. and i do not want to create a linear layout for each button and the layouts spaced evenly.

Edit: this is the code for the images that i use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/page6p"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/page6" />
</selector>
```

Comment: increase layout weight like for button.

Comment: I don't understand. what is the current output of this code ?

Comment: You must do it on xml? or you can do it programmatically, just place the buttons there, in run-time, calculate the size of the screen, divided the size and assign equally to each and every button. Hope this helps.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: @njzk2 current output is that buttons do not get rezized, on a nexus 4 button 1,2,3,4 are shown and button 5 is only showing half the other half is off screen and so are button 6,7 are off screen.

Comment: @user2652394, yes it must be done in XML.

Comment: I checked your code and I remove all background of buttons, they are perfectly equal size, something wrong related to your background images? I just set all `layout_width` as `wrap_content`. Try yourself, maybe problem is the background images.

Comment: i tried, i added some info about my background images. it seems like the image is causing the issue, but i dont know what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not have given button width 0, if you are giving it 0 then layout_weight will not work.

Try giving width and height of Button to `wrap_content`

**UPDATE , Try this**

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button21"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button31"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button41"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button51"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button61"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button71"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

the result is

[image]

Comment: wrap_content does not solve the issue, i was told to use a width of 0 from multiple answers to a question similar to mine,but it does not work for me.

Comment: try it, if your width is defined 0 then layout_weight will not work, because it will not able to make your buttons distribute evenly!

Comment: i tried wrap_content for width and height, it did not fix the issue.

Comment: I think you have some issues with your images, coz your code is working fine in my xml.

Comment: i added some info about my images. i have no idea what i can change in the xml or image to make it work.

Comment: if you are using your images then try to make them small in size and then try to use them or you can wrap your images which ever works for you.